# Is this the correct way to add a page with hook_menu()?

Tags: 7, routes

I'm trying to create a page through `hook_menu()` so I can add my custom block with context instead.

```php
function my_module_menu() {
    $items['my_page'] = array(
        'title' => 'my_page',
        'description' => 'my_page',
        'page callback' => 'my_function',
        'access callback' => true,
    );
    $items['my_page2'] = array(
        'title' => 'my_page2',
        'description' => 'my_page2',
        'page callback' => 'my_function',
        'access callback' => true,
    );
    return $items;
}

function my_function() {
    return '';
}
```

Is it the right way to do it?
I have some bug from time to time, like the block goes missing on those pages. Could it be related to that?

Answer (score 0):

No, the menu items are fine. The problem seems with your block display configuration settings.

There is no permission with these menu items; give some loosely coupled permission (such as *access content*) to these callbacks. Function names should be prefixed with the module name to avoid clashes with other modules.

```php
function my_module_menu() {
  $items['my_page'] = array(
    'title' => 'my_page',
    'description' => 'my_page',
    'page callback' => 'my_module_my_function',
    'access arguments' => 'access content',
  );

  $items['my_page2'] = array(
    'title' => 'my_page2',
    'description' => 'my_page2',
    'page callback' => 'my_module_my_function',
    'access arguments' => 'access content',
  );

  return $items;
}

function my_module_my_function() {
  return '';
}
```

Comment: I rename for this example but the callback prefix was my module name. I was also thinking about 'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM, are you sure that access arguments is making my issue? thx

Comment: If the module name is really my, then `my_module_menu()` would not be recognized as `hook_menu()` implementation, except in the case there is a my_module.module.

Comment: Let's assume that the module name is yop, then I called yop_menu() and yop_callbackfunction()

Comment: Yup if the module name is yop then hook_menu should be yop_menu() {} The callback function name can be anything but as per drupal coding standards it should be prefixed with your module name i.e. yop in your case.

Comment: the functions are called properly in my code, that wasn't the issue, I was thinking there might be something else like the return '' which could be buggy?

Comment: No Return is fine.You have some thing mismatch in your block configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want create `menu item` with `hook_menu` add

```
    'menu_name' => 'yourmenu-machinename', // This is the changed line.
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
```

And as example

```
 $items['my_page'] = array(
    'title' => 'my_page',
    'description' => 'my_page',
    'page callback' => 'my_module_my_function',
    'access arguments' => 'access content',
     'menu_name' => 'yourmenu-machinename', // This is the changed line.
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,

);
```